Modelling a Message Flow or Sequence between Applications
The question is similar to https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html, but not the same.
I want to model a sequence diagram that shows some kind of message flow or sequence between applications: App1 > App2 > App1.
I see two possibilities:

UML Sequence Diagram:
https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html shows my
concerns which are mentioned below.
Archimate “Application Component Sequence Diagram View”: like the one shown in
Diagram similar to the UML Sequence Diagram with Archimate

The problem with Archimate is that it does not really show / model a sequence (which has already been mentioned by Geert in https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html). The sequence is interpreted by the human because the sequence is read from top to bottom.
So, back to the well-known UML Sequence Diagram. The problem here is that App2 > App1 can only be modelled as a return (dashed line) or as a callback (which creates an overlapping execution box) (see picture below). But App2 > App1 is neither a return nor a callback. Because App2 calls App1 without the intention of calling App1 back or to return something. App2 just processes the flow.

My questions are:

Is there another standard diagram (other than Archimate or UML sequence diagram) available to model a simple (message) sequence between applications and that does not confused with callback or return?
If not, how is it possible to use a UML sequence diagram without using a callback (because it is not a callback and the overlapping execution box even emphasizes this) or a return (because it is not a return and the dashed line even emphasizes this)? Interruptions would also useful, showing that the application has its job done (see the picture below as first draft).



Can you specify the scenario you are trying to model?
My guess is that you are trying to model a call from App1 to App2 that initiates action there but finishes its own action without (explicit) return. Am I right?

you seem to be confusing what the callback is here.
If you have no call from App1 to App2 then you just model it the usual way and that's fine.
If you have App1 calling App2, whether it expects the call back from App2 is irrelevant. If App2 is calling as a result of that call App1, that is considered a callback.
Now obviously return is the response to the original call. The callback is just "hey I need something extra from you since you've called me already" kind of deal.
Either way, as I wrote in my answer, UML doesn't limit you here at all.

No, I just want to model a sequence. The services do not need a callback / return. They are just called later as part of a sequence.

Like I mention in the answer, what you try to model is a callback based on one of the callback definitions. Anyway, I hope the answer and all the clarifications in the comments make it crisp clear now ;-)

Firstly, let me say that the term callback may be misinterpreted and I have seen two mutually exclusive definitions of it, one being a call to the originally calling application after the original operation finishes, the other being a call to the originally calling while the first application didn't finish its operation, causing an overlapping processing. The way the question is phrased suggests the latter is taken into consideration. This is what I will assume in this answer. Note also that uml-diagrams considers both situations as callbacks, leaving pretty much no other possibility, which begs the question, what specific scenario do you have in mind that is not a callback.
Secondly, UML does not define a callback as such. The word does not show anywhere in the 2.5.1 version of the specification. I've checked. UML defines only three possible types of messages, one of them being a response to the original synchronous call (return). The other two are pretty much unbound by any conditions when they can be used (synchronous call, asynchronous call or signal - those two are not distinguished by UML notation in sd).
Thirdly, whatever call is being used, the receiving application has to process it somehow and that explains the execution occurrence existence. The return is practically the only type of a message that typically does not need its individual execution occurrence as it is by definition expected and processed within the execution occurrence that has triggered the call. I can however imagine that the process creates a listener that is actually capturing further incoming calls, meaning there is in a way no separate execution occurrence (one can discuss if that actually is the case as each incoming call triggers some analysis of it).
UML in no way prevents you from having a call from App2 to App1 that is neither a return nor a callback (whichever of the two definitions we take here). Note however, that some tools may make it... well, somewhat more difficult. Typically though for a good reason as this approach.
I could imagine just one more or less standard scenario where the call from App2 to App1 occurring after the initial call from App1 to App2 is neither a return nor a callback (that is doesn't not cause an overlapping execution occurrence) and that is, when the App1 already has finished its action that triggered the call to App1 before App2 calls App1. It seems to be exactly what you are looking for.
Now this can happen (and can be modelled) in two ways:

Asynchronous call from App1 to App2.
Implicit return after the synchronous call from App1 to App2.

Let's analyse both cases.

Asynchronous call/signal from App1 to App2.


An asynchronous call/signal is depicted by the solid line with an open arrow. In such case no return is expected and the execution occurrence can finish immediately after the initial message from App1 to App2. As a result, the message coming from App2 to App1 will be below the original execution occurrence in App1. It will still start a new execution occurrence in App1, just not an overlapping one. This situation is depicted (and still called callback) in the diagram you've linked from uml-diagrams page (the <> after the <> on the first diagram). From Proxy perspective you may treat the call as asynchronous from window even though it was effectively processed (validated) by Comments.

Implicit return after the synchronous call from App1 to App2.


The specification states that the return to the synchronous call does not have to be explicitly depicted on the diagram. In such case the implicit return can happen and the execution occurrence can end without having an incoming return. Then, the call from App2 will again have to be below the original execution occurrence that started the initial call to App2.
Note, that some tools may not support some of the situations described here, but UML supports it fully.
One last note (not applicable after the question edit but left for others that might find this answer useful): it might also be the case that you are trying to model on a single diagram something, that essentially suits more as two separate integrations and theoretically should be depicted on two separate diagrams. You may still show it on one UML sequence diagram, but even less modelling tools will help you with that.
Taking all this into consideration UML sequence diagram is a correct choice for you and the diagram you have in your questions is valid (of course the dashed lines should continue and the execution occurrences should start at the message ends, but I realise it's due to tools limitation). This is the option 2 I proposed (implicit return), based on comments I would also still consider the asynchronous call rather than synchronous (option 1).
Like I've mentioned earlier, not all tools support such possibility and for those that do you may still need to do some "tricks" to actually create such diagrams. Finally I believe more tools support such model with asynchronous call.
Two last things to consider:

If you use synchronous call, the proper implementation has to have the return somewhere. The return may just be the confirmation of the message reception (not the result of processing) sent as an immediate response to the request (e.g. 200/202/204 HTTP codes depending on the approach). So if everything else fails and you do insist on using synchronous call, you may add immediate explicit return. It will still be correct diagram. However I would heavily opt for an asynchronous call in your case.
If you struggle how to create the diagram you want in your specific tool (now that you know it is valid) I would recommend you add a second question "How to create such sequence diagram in ".


Many thanks at @Ister. Very helpful.
I want to model that A calls B in a fire and forget mode. So, the execution of A gets terminated. B later calls A because A provides capabilities useful for B. This call is completely independent of the first call. So, I would like to get that B connects to a new execution of A (and not to an overlapping one, because this is not "active" anymore / does not expect a return or callback). So, is it possible / does it make sense with regard to the specification to terminate the execution of A and create a new one for the second call from B to A?

That was my guess and that's exactly what I meant by option 1 in my answer (the asynchronous call), however technically both allow you to achieve the same result.
I'll try to add a diagram tomorrow. I don't remember if SPARX Enterprise Architect allows to draw it this way.
I would recommend you add the clarification through edition of the question. This way someone may provide another answer, also it will be clearer for other people looking for a solution to a similar problem.

Hi @Ister, I updated the text and added pictures. Does that clarify my request?

@Micky it does and my answer stands. I would still recommend considering asynchronous calls rather than synchronous. I've added some additional information to the response to address the new/clarified details.
If you find my answer useful and it answers your question, please consider marking it as an accepted answer.

Many, many thanks, @Ister. Very helpful.
"App1 already has finished its action that triggered the call to App1 before App2 calls App1. It seems to be exactly what you are looking for." Yes, exactly. App1 > App2 is a REST-call, so synchrounous. Can I use an asynchronous relationship anyway? Does this not mean that I am using something like Kafka?
Yes, App2 > App1 is a new situation. App2 does not call App1 because App1 is waiting for something.

While technically REST is a synchronous call, the way it is handled can make the logic of the call asynchronous. If the response is only to confirm the message has been received but doesn't provide any other value, you can treat it as asynchronous.
